# LWJGL: glDrawElements() causes crash in native code

Tags: java, scala, lwjgl

I'm trying to draw a basic cube; at this point I'm not even bothering with perspective projection and am just trying to get something on the screen without a crash. The crash occurs when I call `glDrawElements()` with the following error message:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff838fdbdd, pid=683, tid=1811
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_51-b16) (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [GLEngine+0x159bdd]  gleRunVertexSubmitImmediate+0x42d
...
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
```

My cube vertices and elements are stored in literal arrays:

```
val cubeVertices = Array[Float] (
    // Front face
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    ... // Other faces also defined in same manner
)

val cubeElements = Array[Short] (
    0,  1,  2,      0,  2,  3,    // front
    4,  5,  6,      4,  6,  7,    // back
    8,  9,  10,     8,  10, 11,   // top
    12, 13, 14,     12, 14, 15,   // bottom
    16, 17, 18,     16, 18, 19,   // right
    20, 21, 22,     20, 22, 23    // left
)
```

My window creation code is as follows:

```
glfwInit()

glfwDefaultWindowHints()
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

val window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Hello!", NULL, NULL)

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)
glfwSwapInterval(1)

glfwShowWindow(window)

GLContext.createFromCurrent()

initDraw()

while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE) {
  glfwWaitEvents()
  draw()
  glfwSwapBuffers(window)
}
```

`initDraw()` is defined as follows:

```
val cubeVertexNIOBuffer = createFloatBuffer(cubeVertices.length)
cubeVertexNIOBuffer.put(cubeVertices)
val cubeVertexBuffer = glGenBuffers()
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexBuffer)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexNIOBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

val cubeElementNIOBuffer = createShortBuffer(cubeElements.length)
cubeElementNIOBuffer.put(cubeElements)
val cubeElementBuffer = glGenBuffers()
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeElementBuffer)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeElementNIOBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

cubeVertexArray = glGenVertexArrays()
glBindVertexArray(cubeVertexArray)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexBuffer)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeElementBuffer)

... // Shader compilation and linking stuff
```

And finally, `draw()` is defined as follows:

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glUseProgram(shaderProgram)
glBindVertexArray(cubeVertexArray)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)
```

I have confirmed that `glDrawElements()` is the culprit, as the code runs without crashing when the call is commented out. I am also fairly certain that the shader code is not to blame, as no OpenGL errors are generated by the call to `glUseProgram()`.

I should also note that regular calls to `glDrawArrays()` crash in the same way.

Comment: I believe you need to rewind the buffers after filling them with data. Try a `.position(0)` call after the `.put()` calls on both buffer `NIOBuffer` objects.

Comment: @RetoKoradi That did the trick! Thank you!